# Dom manipulation removal doesn't properly work

Tags: javascript

I'm making a generic todolist, except the li removal part isn't like it should, for testing purposes I created 7 lis to be instantly added when the page loads, all have ids set to them, this is what happens when i try to remove them. (Their names are numbers so "number 1" is the first li)
(The html is just a UL)

number 1 has id of 0

number 2 has id of 1

number 3 has id of 2

number 4 has id of 3

number 5 has id of 4

number 6 has id of 5

number 7 has id of 6

Deleted 7 then  1

error at 6 (Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined)

Pressed 2 and 3 got deleted

pressed 2 and 4 got deleted

pressed 5 and error

pressed 2 and 5 got deleted

pressed 2 and 6 got deleted

I know that this could be improved in MANY ways, you don't need to tell me that.

```
let wholeObject = {

    todos: [],

  //THIS ADDS TO THE ARRAY CALLED TODOS (BUT NOT THE LI, this a work in progress)
addTodo: function(name){
    this.todos.push(name)
},

  //THIS TAKES THE LAST ITEM IN THE ARRAY AND PUSHES IT AS AN LI AND MAKES A BUTTON ON IT
pushLast: function() {



        let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        let uuh = ul.appendChild(li);
        uuh.textContent = this.last()

        for (let q = 0; q <= this.todos.length; q++ ){
            uuh.setAttribute("id", [q -1])
        };

        let btn = document.createElement("button");

        let btnCreate = uuh.appendChild(btn);
        btnCreate.textContent = "Delete";
        btnCreate.className = "buttonClass"
        // btnCreate.setAttribute("onclick", "wholeObject.remove()")
},

delete: function (position){
    this.todos.splice(position, 1)
},



let ulSelect = document.querySelector("ul")

ulSelect.addEventListener("click", function(event){

    let test = event.target

    if (test.className === "buttonClass"){


        wholeObject.delete(parseInt(test.parentNode.id));
        let please = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        please[parseInt(test.parentNode.id) ].remove()

        }
    })
```

Comment: You need to choose better variable names:  `please`, and `test`, and `wholeObject`

Comment: `parseInt(test.parentNode.id)` <-- so did you debug to see what this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several syntax errors and naming issues. Not really sure why you even need/want the array in the first place since the `li` elements that you add to the `ul` create a node list (which already is an array-like object). With the array, you now have two lists that you have to keep in sync. I kept it for demonstration, but in real life, I'd get rid of it.

See comments below:

```js
// Just get this once:
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

let toDoList = {

  todos: [],
  insertItem: function () {

    let li = document.createElement("li");
    
    // Completely configure nodes before inserting them into the DOM
    // to avoid unecessary DOM reparsing and document re-flowing
    li.textContent = "Item: " + this.todos.length;
    li.id = this.todos.length;
    this.todos.push(li);  // Add li to array of li items
    
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.textContent = "Delete";
    btn.className = "buttonClass"
    btn.addEventListener("click", this.delete);
    
    li.appendChild(btn);  // Button is complete. Append to li
    ul.appendChild(li);   // li is complete. Append to ul
  },
  // delete is a reserved word - you can't name anything that  
  deleteItem: function (position, node) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);  // Update the array
    ul.removeChild(node);            // Delete the node
  },
};

// Assign a click event to the ul:
ul.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

  // Check to see if the event originated with a button click
  if (event.target.className === "buttonClass") {
    toDoList.deleteItem(event.srcElement.id,event.srcElement.parentNode);
  }
  
});

// Automated function to create items
(function makeItems(num){
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    toDoList.insertItem();
  }
})(10);
```

```css
li {
  margin-bottom:.5em;
}

.buttonClass {
  margin-left:1em;
  border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #606060;
  padding:6px;
  background-color:#a33;
  color:#ff0;
}

.buttonClass:active {
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Damn, thanks for the help. It looks quite a bit different than what I did.